# Trying to deploy firebase functions Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

My cloud functions use to work.
Now I've tried deploying cloud functions and I got:

**Error:**

```
⚠  functions[limitTasksPerCreatorFirestore]: Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (limitTasksPerCreatorFirestore)
⚠  functions[sendEmail]: Deploy Error: Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write@firestore.googleapis.com (sendEmail)
```

My `package.json`:

```
"@google-cloud/firestore": "0.8.1",
"firebase-admin": "5.4.2",
"firebase-functions": "0.7.1",
"nodemailer": "4.2.0"
```

Comment: Exactly the same here

Comment: same error for me. Worked fine until now. This blocks me completely :-(

Comment: Can you show your function that is failing to deploy?

Comment: same problem here.

Comment: Can you share how you declared the function?

Comment: Sure. Here are my functions https://github.com/Metaburn/doocrate/blob/master/functions/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem, and it has now been resolved by the firebase team.

from the firebase slack:

> eob [12:32 AM] 
>   Firebase dev here again with an update on the problems deploying Functions with Firestore triggers.  We believe we have now identified and fixed the problem, with the fix now fully rolled out. Apologies again for the disruption.

i tested now, and my functions are deploying again!

Comment: Firebase dev here confirming my Slack update: We indeed identified and have now resolved an issue affecting deploying of Functions for some projects with Firestore triggers.  Thanks to those who reported the problem, and sorry for the disruption.

Comment: Yes it's working now. Thank you @EamonnO'Brien-Strain

Comment: Hi Eamonn, I am still having same problem, but only with .onUpdate. onWrite, onCreate are working fine.  I have reduced the code in the function to a simple console log, still gives an error on deployment.  "Deployment error.  Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update@firestore.googleapis.com <functionName>

Comment: @JeffPadget did u solve it? i am getting the same error

Comment: Try updating your firebase to the latest version.